# How to set random color to each vertex clump of my model?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I have this low poly tree and I want each isosphere(suppose to be leaves clumps) to be a random color. I don't have the leaves as a separate object, but the clumps of vertices are not connected to the main tree. How would I approach this? I know there is a way to input a random value and then use the color ramp node to determine the colors, but I don't know how to set the individual leaves clumps to random colors. Also keep in mind I'm going to be creating many instances of the tree later on. Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with [Vertex Color](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting/vertex_paint/introduction.html) painting ?

Comment: And do you really want random or random from a palette, like you provide a low and high brightness green and some script can generates Vertex Color layer data for each icosphere based on a random selection from the gradient between the two colors..  -- Truly random colors is probably not so useful? (it might be.. ..)

Comment: Yes, I want random from a color Palette or a color ramp node.